# Why adding <?> to List declaration causes error when converting from String list to Double list?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I'm trying to convert a String list to Double list as follows:

```
List<String> myStringList = Arrays.asList("10.0", "10.5", "5.0");
List<?> myDoubleList = new ArrayList();
for(String s : myStringList){
        myDoubleList.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
}
```

When I remove the `<?>` from list description, it works. It breaks when I add it however. It gives me this error:

> The method add(capture#6-of ?) in the type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments (double)

Why is that ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p It's not a dupe, but the top answer explains the problem.

Comment: Btw, declaring the list like this: List<Object> seems to be working.

Comment: Why isn't it `List<Double>`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Because I need a generic type to avoid code duplication later.

Comment: @SpiderRico It's not clear from your question how `List<?>` will "avoid code duplication later", but the type of `myDoubleList` can't be completely generic since it needs to support adding doubles to it.  What type of lists besides `List<Double>` do you expect to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this is that `List<?>` represents a generic `List` of some unknown type. This `List<?>` could be `List<String>`, `List<Double>`, `List<File>`, or anything really, all of which count as `List<?>`. This means if you have a variable of type `List<?>`, you can't just add a `Double` to it, because `myListOfWildcard.add(someDouble)` would fail if `myListOfWildcard` is actually a `List<String>`, which it could be.

The wildcards (in particular, `List<?>`) aren't as useful for lists that you want to be able to contain anything. For those you generally want to use `List<Object>`. A wildcard would be more useful if you want to allow yourself these special cases. If you have a method and you want it to be able to accept any type of list whether it be `List<String>` or `List<Double>`, this is what `List<?>` is useful for, because any of these is a `List<?>`. However, you lose the ability to assume anything about the actual generic type parameter of the list, which means you can't just add a `Double`.

`List<?>` is a shortcut for `List<? extends Object>`. Wildcard lists are mostly useful as the arguments for a method; you usually don't want to create them yourself. [Collection.containsAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) is a good real world example of their use: In particular, `Collection.containsAll` accepts any `Collection` as its argument. It doesn't have to be a `Collection<Object>`, but it would if `Collection<Object>` where listed as its type instead of `Collection<?>`.

Edit: Added paragraphs from comments.

Comment: *If you have a method and you want it to be able to accept any type of list whether it be List<String> or List<Double>, this is what List<?> is useful for,* Why would you not use a `List<Object>` as well then?

Comment: List<?> is a shortcut for List<? extends Object>. Wildcards are mostly useful as the arguments for a method. You usually don't want to construct them yourself. See [Collection.containsAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) as a real-world example.

Comment: In particular, `Collection.containsAll` accepts any `Collection` as an argument. It doesn't *have* to be a `Collection<Object>`, which it would be if you used that.